# Getting Bad origin error in execution of the proposal?

Tags: pallet, governance, democracy

I have integrated the democracy, collective, scheduler, and treasury pallet into my chain.
Everything is working fine just during the end step when the proposal is executing it is giving me the bad origin error. Please let me know if you can suggest something?[image]

Comment: Can you please share more details about what the proposal is doing, and how you have set up the end to end test here?

Comment: In the proposal, we are just transferring the balance from one account to another.

Comment: In this case, you probably need to use `force_transfer`, instead of `transfer`. As mentioned, if you don't share more specific details, I can't help you figure out the issue.

Comment: Do you have a WS address we can connect to along with the Github repo? TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shawn suggested, for proposals that do transfers, you would need to use [forceTransfer](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#forcetransfersource-multiaddress-dest-multiaddress-value-compactu128) which executes from the root origin.

(The normal [transfer](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#transferdest-multiaddress-value-compactu128) operates from the signer account and is not meant for these operations)